# Find issued certs based on signing templates

Tags: powershell, certificate-authority

I am looking for a way to query on issued certs from my CA based on their signing template. Here is what I start using (based on PSPKI 4.0.0 module);

```
$AllCerts= Get-CertificationAuthority -name CA_Authority | Get-IssuedRequest -Property Email,CertificateTemplate, CertificateTemplateOID
$RelevantInfo = ($AllCerts | ?{$_.CertificateTemplate -eq 'WebServer' -Or $_.CertificateTemplate -eq 'CustomTemplate'})
```

...however, the query isn't finding the 'CustomTemplate' matches. I even try using wildcard logic;

```
$RelevantInfo = ($AllCerts | ?{$_.CertificateTemplate -eq 'WebServer' -Or $_.CertificateTemplate -like '*CustomTemplateName*'})
```

I can see the values are there when I run;

```
Get-CertificateTemplate | Select Name, DisplayName, OID
```

But the query isn't finding matches for the 'CustomTemplateName'. Is there a way to actually get this 'friendly name' information for the issued certificates template?

Comment: Are the stars around the -like operator a SE formatting thing?

Comment: Your query is working fine for me (except the already mentioned asterisks around the `-like` of course).

Comment: Sorry for the asterisks around the like operator - I must have applied the wrong formatting when I was drafting this message.  I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom templates, `$row.CertificateTemplate` property contains template Object Identifier (OID), not name. Name is returned only for V1 templates (built-in and non-editable).

So in your case, you have to get requested template OID first, then do filter:

```
$AllCerts= Get-CertificationAuthority -name CA_Authority | Get-IssuedRequest -Property Email,CertificateTemplate, CertificateTemplateOID
$OID = (Get-CertificateTemplate -Name 'CustomTemplate').Oid.Value
$RelevantInfo = ($AllCerts | ?{$_.CertificateTemplate -eq 'WebServer' -Or $_.CertificateTemplate -eq $OID})
```

Comment: I'm getting a name for our custom templates, not the OID.

Comment: There are two certificate template related properties: `CertificateTemplate` and `CertificateTemplateOid`. Former returns template common name for V1 templates and OID for V2+ templates (in exact way they are stored in CA DB). It cannot store custom template name. Latter (`CertificateTemplateOid`) property contains resolved template (if possible) with OID and display name (which is often different from common name).